# Update Salesforce Case information

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have created a button to escalate a case. I am trying to change the record type, the "Owner" and append "Case Escalated" to the "Notes" field.

Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}

var objCase = new sforce.SObject('Case');
objCase.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
objCase.Owner__c = 'Global Salesforce Team';
objCase.RecordTypeId = '012C00000007l5WIAQ';
objCase.Notes__c += 'Case Escalated';

var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);
if(result[0].success=='true'){
    alert('The Case was Updated Successfully');
    location.reload(true);
} else if(result[0].success=='true'){
    alert('There was an issue updating the case');
}
```

However this wipes the "Notes" field and adds in "undefinedCase Escalated" instead of appending the string "Case Escalated" to the end of whatever is in there.

I am new to javascript, please be nice :)

Comment: I've not used the sforce js library, so this is just a guess:  objCase.Notes__c = objCase.Notes__c + 'Case Escalated';  I'm aware that is what we'd  expect from +=, but maybe it behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw the code and the problem seems to be that you are creating a new instance of the Case to update, so there is nothing on the field Notes, and once you insert the record it overwrites with the only text there, 'Case Escalated', to get this to work you have to do a query to look for the value that was before on the field and then append the value to the notes__c field.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("select Id, Owner__c, RecordTypeId, Notes__c from      Case WHERE Id='{!Case.Id}' LIMIT 1");
var records = result.getArray('records');

var objCase = records[0];
objCase.Owner__c = 'Global Salesforce Team';
objCase.RecordTypeId = '012C00000007l5WIAQ';
objCase.Notes__c += 'Case Escalated';

var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);
if(result[0].success=='true'){
    alert('The Case was Updated Successfully');
location.reload(true);
} else if(result[0].success=='true'){
    alert('There was an issue updating the case');
}
```

The link to the developer guide with an example is at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/apex_ajax.pdf

Havent tested it and there is some error handling to be done in my code, but it should work.